# WordPress redirecting to Apache port

Tags: wordpress

I've finally got my server up and running using Nginx as the frontend listening on port 80 and Apache listening on 8080 but there's no problem there, the actual problem resides with WordPress...

The issue is every time I login it redirects to:
http://www.site.com:8080/

Which breaks a few things on WordPress for some reason, like I can't insert images to the posts as I get Permission Denied from Firebug so without :8080 being added on to the URL everything works correctly.

So does anyone know a fix or a file I need to modify in WordPress or whatever - I would greatly appreciate it!

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're after this document:

```
http://wordpress.org/support/topic/wordpress-behind-reverse-proxy
```

and specificallly

```
 ProxyPreserveHost On
```

assuming your config is sane. If nginx is a bit messy then a

```
        $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] = "...any host..";
```

to the top of wp-config.php will wack it forcefully into any shape. Bit brute force though.

Comment: Where do I add 'ProxyPreserveHost On' (which file)? As my config files are relatively clean as much as you could hope for, and as you say slapping that bit of php code in there is a bit overkill so i'll leave that to the last resort :)

Comment: Does not matter. Add it to the end I'd say. But only if the Preseve did not work of course.